# Can't call parent class method in Rails singleton

Tags: ruby-on-rails, singleton

I have some class CurrentUser

```
class CurrentUser < User
    include Singleton
end
```

User is ActiveRecord::Base
CurrentUser.instance.find(1) returns "`find` method is not found"
What's wrong with it?

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, what are you trying to do? Are you trying to coerce a special class on one particular member of a Model represented in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` is a *class* method of `ActiveRecord::Base`, whereas `CurrentUser.instance` provides an *instance* of (a subclass of) that class.

Does `CurrentUser.find(1)` work? I haven't used `Singleton`, so I don't know if it interferes with Rails in exciting ways.

Comment: Noooop. "private method `allocate' called for #<Class:0x62f3040>"

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your Model

```
self.public_class_method :allocate
```